# .htaccess Not Connected, How To Get File Path?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am working on a website. More specifically I am working with permalinks and .htaccess files (not wordpress). Anyhow, I have my current .htaccess file setup, but it is not being used for some reason. So I read up, and I found out that I need to change something in my apache config, and I am trying to.

I guess I have to change the , but I do not know what path to set for it. The defualt example is set up like this:

```
<Directory wamp/www/'>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

For the file path, I am confused on what I should set. My files are currently like this:

> Wamp > WWW > postin' > profiles > profile.htaccess and profile.php

Now I tried the path: ***wamp/www/postin'/profiles*** and ***wamp/www/postin'/profiles/profile.htaccess***, yet neither seem to work. What is the path I should be setting, and is the current directory I have set correct? Also if you want here is my profile.htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f  
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} &gt;""
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ postin'/profiles/profile.php?user=$1 [L]</pre>
```

and here is my profile.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<?php

require("C:\wamp\www\postin'\db_connection.php");

$urlname = explode("/",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$urlquery = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE permalink = :permalink";
$urlparams = array(':permalink' => $urlname[3]);

try{
    $urlstmt = $connection->prepare($urlquery);
    $urlresult = $urlstmt->execute($urlparams);
}

catch(PDOException $ex){
    echo ("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
}

$urlcolumns = $urlstmt->fetch();
$urlfetch = $urlcolumns["username"];

if(!$urlcolumns){
  print_r(apache_get_modules());
}

else {
    echo $urlfetch;
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

So my main question is what path should I set? Thank You! :)

P.S. If you could help me with the link I have in the profile.htaccess that would be great too! :)

Comment: did you name your file "profile.htaccess"? it should be only .htaccess I guess

Comment: Hello, I tried naming it .htaccess and it said "please enter a name"

Comment: where exactly did you get that message? while renaming? then it is the tool you used for renaming it, that is not able to name files with a beginning dot